# Get region name using MaxMind's GeoLite

Tags: php, geoip, ip-geolocation, maxmind

I'm a bit confused by how to get the region name and cannot find any documentation on it.
I have the database installed wich it 'GeoIP.dat' and 'geoip.inc' in this directory '...IP GeoLite\GeoLite' and i also have a php page for the test \IP GeoLite\find.php 
the code inside the  'find.php' page is it didn't work :

```
<?php
/* Instead of having to determine the country of the client every time they visit the site we are going to set 
a cookie so that any other script in PHP or Javascript can use the region information. 
The user is also given a menu option to change the region and reset the cookie to a new value.
Likewise, if it already exists we don't want to change it.
We start off by checking that the cookie called Region exists. 
If it does, the job is nearly done and we simply set the $Region variable so that we can refresh 
the cookie at the end of the program by recreating it. */
 if(isset($_COOKIE['Region']))
 {
  $Region = $_COOKIE['Region'];
 }
 else
/* Only if the cookie isn't set do we do the actions in the else part of the if, 
so this makes the whole thing efficient.
To make use of the GeoLite code we have to load the include file: */
{ 
  $GeoPath= 'GeoLite/'; 
  include($GeoPath.'geoip.inc'); 
}
  $countrydata = GeoIP_region_name_by_code(gir->country_code, gir->region) ;
  echo $countrydata ;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must open the Geo IP binary data file first

```
// Open Geo IP binary data file
$geoIp = geoip_open($GeoPath.'GeoIP.dat',GEOIP_STANDARD);
```

Look at this documentation http://www.maxmind.com/download/geoip/api/php.old/README